# how to fix key pressed function for changing Jlabel into valid values

Tags: java, swing, keypress

I'm working with conversion degrees, once user enters value into text field pointing out which degree is needed,  the input with output result should appear instead of the label was before.
   Here section for formatting restriction for letters input only for numbers in the text field

```
        NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance();
        NumberFormatter formatter = new NumberFormatter(format);
        formatter.setValueClass(Double.class);
        formatter.setMinimum(Double.MIN_VALUE);
        formatter.setMaximum(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        formatter.setAllowsInvalid(false);
        formatter.setCommitsOnValidEdit(true);
        formattedTextField = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);

        formattedTextField.setColumns(10);

      }
```

here the problem

```
      public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        double degree;
        if (Angle.isSelected()||e.getKeyChar()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
          degree = Math.toDegrees((double)formattedTextField.getValue());
          resultLabel.setText(formattedTextField.getValue() 
   + " ° = "+ degree + " radians");

  }else if(Radians.isSelected()||e.getKeyChar()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
 degree = Math.toRadians((double) formattedTextField.getValue());
          resultLabel.setText(formattedTextField.getValue() + 
 " radians = " + degree + " °");
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Actually, i wanted from key Enter in the text field simultaneously converts value in the proper value, depending on the chosen degree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you’re using `||` (or) instead of `&&` (and).  Your `if` tests don’t require the key being pressed to be ENTER;  they require that the key is ENTER, *or* one of the radio buttons (Angle or Radians) is selected.

All that said… it doesn’t matter, because you should not use a KeyListener for this.  Normally, you check for the user pressing Enter in a JTextField by [adding an ActionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTextField.html#addActionListener%28java.awt.event.ActionListener%29), but JFormattedTextField has a better way, which monitors not only Enter but also loss of focus:  [the documentation for JFormattedTextField’s value property](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html#setValue%28java.lang.Object%29) states that it is a bound property, which means you can [listen to changes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Container.html#addPropertyChangeListener%28java.lang.String,java.beans.PropertyChangeListener%29) in that property:

```
formattedTextField.addPropertyChangeListener("value",
    new PropertyChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void propertyChangeEvent(PropertyChangeEvent event) {
            Double newValue = (Double) event.getNewValue();
            if (newValue != null) {
                if (angle.isSelected()) {
                    double radians = Math.toRadians(newValue);
                    resultLabel.setText(
                        newValue = + " ° = " + radians + " radians");
                } else {
                    double degree = Math.toDegrees(newValue);
                    resultLabel.setText(
                        newValue + " radians = " + degree + " °");
                }
            }
        }
    });
```